# Do windows 10 recovery drives contain licence information?

Tags: windows

Basically if I run recoverydrive create on two same model machines, will all the files be equal or not

Comment: They will be different

Comment: @whs Can you provide a source for that? If so, you can make it into an answer.

Comment: The title asks whether the recovery partition contains the license info.  The question, itself, asks whether a recovered system will have the same files.  What is your actual question?

Comment: You can try to do two [recovery drives](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/create-a-recovery-drive) on two usb and (1) compare them file by file, and check on which they will be different and/or (2) try to _"Get Product Key from my Recovery partition"_  in the [_"registry hive"_](http://www.sevenforums.com/installation-setup/239518-get-product-key-my-recovery-partition-2.html) (if it still works, it worked in windows 7...) or with other methods.